# I keep getting a segfault anyone know why? In C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

The problem seems to occur when qsort is called or if I add more than one monster then try to add a monster I have already added.

Header File:

```
#ifndef UTILS_H_
#define UTILS_H_

#define MAX_MONSTERS 32
#define MAX_LEN 128

#define FILTER_NAME 1
#define FILTER_HP 2
#define FILTER_AC 3
#define FILTER_STATS 4
#define EXIT_CHOICE 5

void trim(char *);

typedef struct {
    char name[MAX_LEN];
    char type[MAX_LEN];
    int hp;
    int ac;
    int str;
    int dex;
    int con;
} monster_s;

struct node_s {
    void *data;   // Pointer to the monster_s struct
    int roll;     // The roll value
    int position; // The original position in the array (after sorting)
    struct node_s *next;
};

int load_monster_csv(monster_s **, FILE *);

void add_to_order(monster_s *, struct node_s *,  int);

void display_order(struct node_s *);

void parse_monster(monster_s *, char *);


#endif
```

Utils.c

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>


#include "queue_utils.h"

void trim(char *str)
{
    int l = strlen(str);
    if (str[l - 1] == '\n')
    {
        str[l - 1] = 0;
    }
}

int is_in_order(monster_s monsters_ptr, struct node_s *initiativeOrder, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        monster_s *current_monster = (monster_s *)initiativeOrder[i].data;
        if (current_monster == NULL)
        {
            printf("Assignment failed I don't know why.");
        }
        
        printf("Checking %s against %s\n", monsters_ptr.name, current_monster->name);

        if (!strcmp(monsters_ptr.name, current_monster[i].name))
        {
            // Monster already in order
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;      
}

struct node_s *enqueue(struct node_s *head, monster_s *data, int pos, int roll) {
    struct node_s *new_node = calloc(1, sizeof(struct node_s));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    new_node->position = pos;
    new_node->roll = roll;

    if (head == NULL) {
        head = new_node;
    } else {
        struct node_s *current = head;
        while (current->next != NULL)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = new_node;
    }
    return head;
}

void add_to_order(monster_s *monsters_ptr, struct node_s *initiativeOrder, int numbersRead)
{
    int count = 0;
    char input[MAX_LEN];
        do
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numbersRead; i++)
            {
                printf("(%d) %s\n", i + 1, monsters_ptr[i].name);
            }

            printf("(C) Continue\n");
            scanf(" %s", input);
            if (isdigit(input[0]))
            {                
                if(atoi(input) >= 0 && atoi(input) <= numbersRead)
                {
                    int added = is_in_order(monsters_ptr[atoi(input) - 1], initiativeOrder, count);
                    if (added)
                    {
                        printf("%s has already been added.\n", monsters_ptr[atoi(input) - 1].name);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        initiativeOrder = realloc(initiativeOrder, sizeof(struct node_s) * (count + 1));                    
                        initiativeOrder[count].data = &monsters_ptr[atoi(input) - 1];
                        // *initiativeOrder = enqueue(*initiativeOrder, &monsters_ptr[atoi(input) - 1], count, 0);
                        printf("%s added to order.\n", monsters_ptr[atoi(input) - 1].name);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Invalid Input\n");
                }
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                switch (input[0])
                {
                case 'C':
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("Invalid Input\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (input[0] == 'C')
            {
                break;
            }
        } while (1);
}

void parse_monster(monster_s *monster, char *csv_line)
{
    char *token = strtok(csv_line, ",");

    int attr = 0;

    while (token)
    {
        switch (attr)
        {
        case 0:
            strcpy(monster->name, token);
            break;
        case 1:
            strcpy(monster->type, token);
            break;
        case 2:
            monster->hp = atoi(token);
            break;
        case 3:
            monster->ac = atoi(token);
            break;
        case 4:
            monster->str = atoi(token);
            break;
        case 5:
            monster->dex = atoi(token);
            break;
        case 6:
            monster->con = atoi(token);
            break;
        }
        attr++;
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
}

int load_monster_csv(monster_s **monsters_ptr, FILE *fp)
{
    char buffer[MAX_LEN] = {0};
    int num_read = 0;

    while (fgets(buffer, MAX_LEN, fp))
    {
        trim(buffer);
        monster_s *temp_monster = (monster_s *)malloc(sizeof(monster_s));
        parse_monster(temp_monster, buffer);

        *monsters_ptr = (monster_s *)realloc(*monsters_ptr, sizeof(monster_s) * (num_read + 1));
        // Reminder not to forget the parentheses for (*monster_ptr)
        // If forgotten you will get the error Segmentation fault
        (*monsters_ptr)[num_read] = *temp_monster;
        free(temp_monster);

        num_read++;
    }

    return num_read;
}
```

Main

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "queue_utils.h"

int roll_dice()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int dice = (rand() % 20) + 1;
    printf("%d", dice);
    return dice;
}

void roll_order(struct node_s *initiativeOrder)
{
    struct node_s *current = initiativeOrder;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        current->roll = roll_dice();
        current = current->next;
    }
}

int compare_rolls(const void *elem1, const void *elem2)
{
    struct node_s *turnOrderA = (struct node_s *)elem1;
    struct node_s *turnOrderB = (struct node_s *)elem2;

    return turnOrderB->roll - turnOrderA->roll;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Validate input arguments
    if (argc == 1)
    {
        printf("Incorrect Input\nCorrect Input: ./a.out FILEPATH");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    // Attempt to open file given by first command line argument
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    monster_s *monsters_ptr = NULL;
    struct node_s initiativeOrder;
    int numbersRead = load_monster_csv(&monsters_ptr, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    add_to_order(monsters_ptr, &initiativeOrder, numbersRead);
    qsort(&initiativeOrder, numbersRead, sizeof(struct node_s), compare_rolls);
    return 0;
}
```

Data from csv file:

```
Acolyte,HUMANOID,9,10,5,5,5
Adult Black Dragon,DRAGON,195,19,11,7,10
Goblin,HUMANOID,7,15,4,7,5
Gold Dragon Wyrmling,DRAGON,60,17,9,7,8
Bearded Devil,FIEND,52,13,8,7,7
Rakshasa,FIEND,110,16,7,8,9
```

I have tried to pass just the address to the function add_to_order but that did not work either I did change this (struct node_s *initiativeOrder = NULL;) to this struct node_s initiativeOrder;) when I tried that

Comment: `initiativeOrder` is a null pointer, you can't sort that.

Comment: The value of initiativeOrder is assigned in the function add_to_order.

Comment: That's local to that function, it doesn't affect the variable in `main()`. If you want to update the variable in `main()`, you have to do it similar to the way you do `monsters_ptr` in `load_monster_csv()`.

Comment: I now pass add_to_order the address of initiativeOrder. I also removed the pointer from the initiativeOrder declaration however I still get the same error.

Comment: You still need a pointer in the declaration of `initiativeOrder`, otherwise it's not an array.

Comment: You have to do this the same way you do `monsters_ptr`.

Comment: Actually, it looks like `initiativeOrder` is supposed to be a linked list. You can't use `qsort` to sort a list, it can only sort arrays.

Comment: The goal is to assign the values to an array first, then sort them, then put them into the linked list. Is there something I did wrong?

Comment: then you should sort `monsters_ptr`, not `initiativeOrder`

Comment: I would like to sort initiativeOrder based on the size of the roll.

Comment: No. Sort the array first, then put them into the linked list.

Comment: I haven't put the values in a linked list yet so that does not matter. I am asking about the segfault.

Comment: Note that running a build compiled with `-g -fsanitize=address` provides good info on segfaults that occur in that run.

Comment: What is `"queue_utils.h"`?

Comment: You _can_ actually use qsort to sort a linked list, but then the linked list needs to be implemented by using an array or memory pool for data storage and not allocate nodes with separate calls to malloc. Which shouldn't be done anyway on "modern" (> year 1990) computers since it is is horribly inefficient. Those algorithm classes that taught you to use linked lists for fast inserting in the middle were wrong - inserting an item by moving an array of adjacent items one item to the side is likely _way_ more efficient on a CPU with a bit of data cache memory, vs individual heap allocations.

Comment: The segfault was probably because you weren't updating `initiaiveOrder` before calling `qsort()`. If you sort `monsters_ptr` instead, things should work.